# Mysql on k8s for developers from external xtrabackup backup

Tags: mysql, kubernetes, percona, kubernetes-operator, percona-xtradb-cluster

The company has a production mysql cluster on the servers and need to place 10-15 environments for developers with their own database, as well as periodically update this database with the sale.
My idea was to use mysql operator, deploy conditional 10 databases from an external backup production mysql database on NFS, but mysql operators does not support it, can you give directions?

Comment: You really want to ask DBAs, not software developers about this.